# Perimeter of Quadrilateral

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

The lengths of two sides of a quadrilateral are equal to 1 and 4. One of the diagonals has a lengths of 2 and divide the quadrilateral into two isosceles triangles. What is the perimeter of the quadrilateral?

[image]

Comment: I guess the quadrilateral is in the form of a kite, as you can divide it into two isosceles triangles...

Comment: In FIG 1, BCD gives you a degenerate triangle (i.e one degenerate to a line segment). Given any three positive numbers $a \le b \le c$, the condition that they can form the sides of a non-degenerate triangle is $a + b \color{red}{>} c$.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the diagonal 2 and a side 1 means that the side 4 does not share the same triangle with the side 1. This means that you have the two isosceles triangle with sides: (1,1) and (4,4). The perimeter of the triangle is 10.

Comment: Is this answer $10$ for a *convex* or a *concave* quadrilateral ??

Comment: It is 10 in both cases.

Comment: Oh!! Yeah !! Really...why don't you try to make a rough figure for the convex quadrilateral case and you will see that the triangles that will made will be while drawing the quadrilateral with appropriate diagonal mentioned will be $(1,1,2)$ and $(4,4,2)$ but as you can see the first triangle is not a triangle(*as iis shown by triangular inequality) !! It is a degenerate triangle and thus such a quadrilateral(*convex*) is not possible to be made with the specifications you have declared...

Comment: The answer is 11. Dont know how? I also guessed it should be 10.

Comment: @user39531 it is $11$, the two triangles are $(4_{known},2_{diagonal},4)$ and $(1_{known},2_{diagonal},2)$

Comment: I was thinking of a scenario as in FIG 1 ( see above). How do you calculate the 2 (side HG), in the triangle (1known, 2 diagonal, 2?) in FIG 2. Are we supposed to use Laws of sine or cosines?

Comment: I realize that there is one solution with 11.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this very complicated ...first thing is that you were indeed going in the right direction but see the figure $1$ that you have made closely..

Note that the triangle ∆BCD has sides $1,1,2$ so this means-*sum of length of the sides $BC,CD$ that is $2$ is equal to $BD$ that is $2$ also* but if you know about triangular inequality you must have realised by now that such a triangle cannot be made (*because according to triangular inequality if the sum of two sides is equal to the third one then it is actually not a triangle*)

So that means the First quadrilateral you have made is not possible.so what should we now,?? Well,we should go in a systematic way instead of just shooting arrows in the air.

Step 1: Make a rough figure(*such as you have made*)First fix the sides that you know(*that is just using the question and leaving the sides that are not known*) so we have now made a quadrilateral $ABCD$ in which $AD=4$,$DC=1$,$BD=2$ are fixed.
[image: quad]

Step 2: Think about the various possibilities. Note that the question says that the triangle $BCD$ must be isosceles but we have already shown that BC cannot be $1$(*by triangular inequality*) so that leaves us with only one possibility that is $BC=2$.So half of the question is done.

Now only one side $AB$ is not known.OK...but we know that $∆BAD$ is isosceles so we have again got two possibilities that is $AB=4$ or $AB=2$ but then again if $AB=2$ ..then by the same reasoning as above this is also not possible(*by triangular inequality*) so that means $AB=4$ is the only possibility left.

Thus now we have got all the sides $AD=4$,$DC=1$,$AB=4$,$BC=2$ adding which we get answer $11$.

Is this information enough.if you need more explainiation just drop a comment below.